# How to add cake path in mac osx 10.6.5

Tags: macos

Can someone explain how you add a cake path in OSX?

Comment: Can you give any more details? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: How to add cake path in mac osx 10.6.5

Answer (score 2):

OK, since you couldn't provide any more explanation aside from repeating the question title, I'll just take a random stab in the dark here...

I'm guessing that you're using the "cake" console in CakePHP? And you want to set up an environment variable (or path) so that you can start it from the terminal? Something like explained [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/108/The-CakePHP-Console)?

If that's the deal, and assuming you're using a standard configuration of Mac OS X 10.6 and the Bash shell, you need to find the `.bashrc` file in your home directory (if one doesn't exist, you'll need to create it), and add the following line:

```
alias cake=my/cake/folder
```

where "my/cake/folder" is the full path to your cake application.

Comment: Right. On OSX, edit and add this to your .bash_profile: alias cake="/[path to your cake app]/app/Console/cake"